# Como unir duas tabelas em um JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tenho duas tabelas:

**Empresas**

```
id: integer
nome: string
```

**Imagens**

```
id: intger
idEmpresa: integer
url: string
```

Faço:

`select * from empresas where id = 1`

`select * from imagens where idempresa = 1`

e gero um arquivo json assim:

`json_encode($resultado);`

Funciona de boa, mas eu sempre tenho que fazer duas consultas (uma em cada tabela).

Como fazer para que o Json seja gerado assim:

```
[{id: 1,
  nome: 'empresa1',
  imagens: {id: 1,
            idEmpresa: 1
            url: '1111'},
           {id: 2,
            idEmpresa: 1
            url: '2222'}
}]
```

Não sei escrever bem o código em json, mas creio que dê pra entender que devem vir todas as imagens que pertence a cada empresa.

Já tentei usar um join, mas ele gera assim:

```
[{"id":"1","nome":"empresa1","idEmpresa":"1","url":"1111"},
{"id":"1","nome":"empresa1","idEmpresa":"1","url":"2222"},
{"id":"1","nome":"empresa1","idEmpresa":"1","url":"3333"}]
```

Ou seja, gera mais de um registro para cada empresa

Alguma dica de como unir as tabelas pra que o resultado saia como eu desejo?

Comment: qual banco de dados você está usando?

Comment: @Phelipe estou usando mysql

Comment: Coloque o código atual que você utiliza para buscar o registro no banco e adicionar no json, vai facilitar a resposta

Comment: Faz um join das tabelas.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `UNION` para fazer a união das duas tabelas.

```
SELECT 
    Empresas.id,
    Empresas.nome,
FROM 
    Empresas
UNION ALL
SELECT
    imagens.idEmpresa,
    imagens.url,
FROM 
    Imagens
WHERE Empresas.id = imagens.idEmpresa
```

Comment: não funciona, ele gera o json assim: `[{"id":"1","nome":"empresa1","idEmpresa":"1","url":"1111"},{"id":"1","nome":"empresa1","idEmpresa":"1","url":"2222"},{"id":"1","nome":"empresa1","idEmpresa":"1","url":"3333"},]`

Ou seja, ao invés de lançar apenas um registro da empresa + as três imagens dentro dela, ele gera três registros

Comment: Editei a resposta, da uma olhada agora. Não percebi que era um relacionamento 1-n